# Remove `NaN` from Pandas Dataframe by Group

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a Dataframe that looks like this:

```
value   attribute1  attribute2  attribute3  attribute4
value1  NaN         NaN         foo         NaN
value1  bar         NaN         NaN         NaN
value1  NaN         baz         NaN         NaN
value1  NaN         NaN         NaN         boo
```

I am trying to find a way to condense the frame so that it looks more like this:

```
value   attribute1  attribute2  attribute3  attribute4
value1  bar         baz         foo         boo
```

***I have not been able to find any specific solutions that will allow me to do this.***

Comment: Will you have more than value in `value` column ?

Comment: @jpp Yeah the actual DF is far larger than what I have shown above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [166]: df.groupby('value').first()
Out[166]:
       attribute1 attribute2 attribute3 attribute4
value
value1        bar        baz        foo        boo
```

or

```
In [167]: df.groupby('value', as_index=False).first()
Out[167]:
    value attribute1 attribute2 attribute3 attribute4
0  value1        bar        baz        foo        boo
```

Comment: Wow, that works! The first one seemed to repeat the value but the second option worked really well, very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

```
df.bfill().iloc[[0]]
Out[201]: 
    value attribute1 attribute2 attribute3 attribute4
0  value1        bar        baz        foo        boo
```

Comment: Hey this is working really great as well, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `sort_values`, then `bfill` and `drop_duplicates`.

This will work for multiple unique values in `value` column, even if they are not ordered.

```
res = df.sort_values('value')\
        .bfill()\
        .drop_duplicates('value')

#     value attribute1 attribute2 attribute3 attribute4
# 0  value1        bar        baz        foo        boo
```